# JavaFX Progressbar not updating with Observer Pattern

Tags: java, javafx

So I have implemented Observer Pattern. In the update function of my Observer class, I want to update the progressbar. The problem is that it instantly updates to the maximum value. I don't get an loading animation. The application calculates some edges. After the calculation of the edges, they will be drawn on the screen.

My observers are the following :

```
 GenerateEdgeBottom

 GenerateEdgeLeft

 GenerateEdgeRight
```

I also have a `KochManager` and an javaFX class.

I make my progressbars in the javaFX class. In the javaFX class is a function that binds all the progressbars.

Part of my javaFX class

```java
 public void binding(GenerateEdgeLeft leftEdges, GenerateEdgeRight rightEdges, GenerateEdgeBottom bottomEdges) {
        progressBarLeft.progressProperty().unbind();
        progressBarLeft.setProgress(0);

        progressBarRight.progressProperty().unbind();
        progressBarRight.setProgress(0);

        progressBarBottom.progressProperty().unbind();
        progressBarBottom.setProgress(0);

        progressBarLeft.progressProperty().bind(leftEdges.progressProperty());
        progressBarRight.progressProperty().bind(rightEdges.progressProperty());
        progressBarBottom.progressProperty().bind(bottomEdges.progressProperty());

        lblLeft.textProperty().bind(leftEdges.messageProperty());
        lblRight.textProperty().bind(rightEdges.messageProperty());
        lblBottom.textProperty().bind(bottomEdges.messageProperty());
    }
```

My kochmanager

```java
 public void changeLevel(int nxt) {
        edges.clear();
        koch.setLevel(nxt);

        this.leftEdgeTask = new GenerateEdgeLeft(koch);
        this.bottomEdgeTask = new GenerateEdgeBottom(koch);
        this.rightEdgeTask = new GenerateEdgeRight(koch);

        tsCalc.init();
        tsCalc.setBegin("Begin calculating");
        //System.out.println("test 3");
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            //System.out.println("test 4");
            application.binding(leftEdgeTask,rightEdgeTask,bottomEdgeTask);

            futures.clear();
            Future<?> f = pool2.submit(bottomEdgeTask);
            Future<?> f2 =pool2.submit(leftEdgeTask);
            Future<?> f3 = pool2.submit(rightEdgeTask);
            futures.add(f);
            futures.add(f2);
            futures.add(f3);

            try {
                edges.addAll(leftEdgeTask.get());
                edges.addAll(rightEdgeTask.get());
                edges.addAll(bottomEdgeTask.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //System.out.println("test 5");
            koch.getEdges().clear();

            tsCalc.setEnd("End calculating");
            application.setTextNrEdges("" + koch.getNrOfEdges());
            application.setTextCalc(tsCalc.toString());
            application.requestDrawEdges();
            drawEdges();
        });
    }
```

My GenerateEdgeLeft

```java
public class GenerateEdgeLeft extends Task<ArrayList<Edge>> implements Observer {
    private KochFractal koch;
    //private KochManager manager;
    private int numberOfEdges;
    private int counter;

    private ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<>();

    public GenerateEdgeLeft(KochFractal koch){
        this.koch = koch;
        numberOfEdges = koch.getNrOfEdges() / 3;
        this.koch.addObserver(this);

    }

    public GenerateEdgeLeft() {
        //edges.size
    }

    public ArrayList<Edge> getResult() {
        return edges;
    }



    @Override
    public ArrayList<Edge> call() throws Exception {
        counter = 0;
        System.out.println("Thread Started Left");
        koch.generateLeftEdge();
        edges = koch.getEdges();

        return edges;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        edges.add((Edge) arg);
        counter++;

        updateProgress(counter, numberOfEdges);
        updateMessage( "Left : " + counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Future::get` is a blocking operation. By calling get in the UI, you block it until the tasks are completed.

Comment: I fixed the progressbars. Now I don't see the drawings on the screen. Can you help me?

Comment: How did you solve the problem? By removing `xxxEdgeTask.get ()`? If yes, then you need to ensure that the completed tasks are handled. Browse the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm for examples of how to use progress synchronization

Comment: I added a done method in my 3 classes.  GenerateEdgeBottom

 GenerateEdgeLeft

 GenerateEdgeRight